# Why does p divides $2^{2(q-1)}-1$ if p divides $2^{q-1}+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does p divides $2^{2(q-1)}-1$ if p divides $2^{q-1}+1$.
The assumptions I have on $p$ and $q$ are that both are uneven and both are prime numbers. Also, besides having the proof, I'm tyring to have the "intuition" between this but I'm struggling.

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing that I found that could maybe be useful is the following: if p divides $2^{q-1}+1$ then p divides $2^{q-1}+2-1$ so p divides $2(2^{q-2}+1)-1$

Comment: Note that $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$.  Find a suitable $x$

Comment: By $\,m=-1\,$ in  linked Factor Theorem: $\, n+1\mid n^2-1.\,$ OP is special case $\,n = 2^{q-1}.\ $

Comment: So $\,p\mid n+1\mid n^2-1\Rightarrow p\mid n^2-1\,$ by transitivity of divisibility (2nd linked dupe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p\:|\:2^{q-1} + 1$ implies $2^{q-1} + 1 = ap$ for some integer $a$.
Notice that $$2^{2(q-1)} - 1 = (2^{q-1} - 1)(2^{q-1} + 1) = (2^{q-1} - 1)ap.$$ Hence $2^{2(q-1)} - 1$ is an integer multiple of $p$, meaning that $p$ divides $2^{2(q-1)} - 1$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:$$2^{2(q-1)}-1=(2^{q-1}-1)(2^{q-1}+1)$$

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).